# How to change the shortcut language in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, language

I recently changed my **Windows 10 display language** from English to Spanish. With this change, the **shortcuts** are now also different.

For example, saving a text document in Notepad is now <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, because ***s***ave translates to ***g***uardar in Spanish.

I would like to have the display language in Spanish but the shortcuts the same as in English. How is it possible to independently modify these two options, if at all?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to add English keyboard (you can have multiple keyboard layouts) and use the English keyboard

To do that

- Click on the Start Menu. ... Click on Settings. Click on Time &
  language. Click on Region & language. Click on the language you wish
  to add a keyboard layout to. Click on Options. Click on Add a
  keyboard. Click on the English keyboard

[image]