# Changed the computer language, now I want to change the shortcut language

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, language

I have changed the language in my computer from Portuguese to English AUS (I had it formatted in Portugal and everything was set to Portuguese), however I prefer to work in an English environment. I have changed the language to English successfully, however , the shortcut languages are still the same as with the PT language. For example CTRL + A is still CTRL + T. I have found a similar topic [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1250084/how-to-change-the-shortcut-language-in-windows-10) however I do not want to change my keyboard to EN as I for example use the ç in daily convos, as this is a standard key on PT keyboards. 
I know it's possible, as I have the desired set-up on my work computer (computer language is EN with keyboard shorts in EN, but keyboard in PT). 
Can anyone shed some light on my problematic shortcut issues?

Thanks in advance!
Jessica

Answer (score 0):

May be the reason behind the wrong keyboard layout choose.

Please select English US keyboard layout to perform what you want.